# Кастомная интерактивная географическая карта на Python

Tags: python, google-maps, карты, plotly, folium

Использую для визуализации чаще всего библиотеку plotly, и в ней есть некоторый функционал для интерактивных географических карт. Мне необходимо сделать интерактивную карту, однако она изначально кастомная (по-существу, есть только .png карты из игры). Каким способом можно создать интерактивную географическую карту на базе карты из игры?

Comment: Можете вставить изображение карты в вопрос? Иначе вряд ли можно сделать интерактивную карту не знаю оригинальной.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Подробнее опишите задачу, пока не очень понятно.

Comment: Есть вот такая картка: https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/State_of_San_Andreas_(3D_Universe)?file=SanAndreas-TerrainMap.jpg
У plotly есть возможность делать интерактивные гео карты: https://plotly.com/python/maps/
Как можно использовать карту игры для создания гео графики, как на второй ссылке?